# can gcc cross compile for different CPU?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

Is it possible for gcc, installed on fedora 16, to cross compile for a different CPU, say SPARC? 
I have build a certain understanding, need some expert to correct me if I am wrong. Different operating systems differ by the system calls they use to access the kernel or entirely by the kernel they use. IS THIS CORRECT?  different kernels understands different systems calls for accessing underlying hardware. binaries or executables or programs are nothing but a bunch of system calls only. therefore every OS has its own executable. an executable meant to run to on windows wound not run on linux. by cross compiling the source code of any windown's executable we can generate executable for other OSs. word PLATFORM means operating system. POSIX are certain design standards for UNIX-like OSs.
we usually cross compile for different OSs. BUT can we cross compile for different hardware too? for example, in case of a microcontroller which does not have an OS?

Comment: The last time I needed a cross-compiler, I found this guide helpful: http://linux.bytesex.org/cross-compiler.html

Comment: @Saurabh: I have written a small tutorial on obtaining a cross compiler for Sparc and running the executable on Qemu emulator. You might find it useful. :https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/course/~nehak/SparcQemu.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You can't use native machine (x86) gcc for compiling program files for a different architecture. For that you require a cross-compiler-gcc that is specific to that processor architecture.

Your understanding about system calls for OS is correct. Each OS has its own set of system call which is been used by library. These libraries at the end will be translated into machine language for the processor.

Each Processor Architecture has its own set of instruction know as Instruction Set Architecture(ISA). So when a program written in high-level-language (like C) is compiled, it should be converted into machine language from its ISA. This job is done by the compiler(gcc). A compiler will be specific to only one processor architecture. For example gcc is for x86 processor. So if you want a compiler for different processor in you x86 machine you should go for a cross-compiler of that processor.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to build such a version. That's part of the process of porting `gcc` to a new platform. You build a version that cross-compiles, then you cross-compile that version, then you test that version on the new platform, debug, rinse, and repeat.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I can only build a gcc-SPARC-version on my intel machine. But can only run and test it on SPARC?

Comment: @Saurabh No, I don't mean to say that at all. I mean to say exactly what I did say. You can build a cross-compiler for SPARC on Intel, run it on Intel, use it to compile itself, and run the result on SPARC.

Comment: o.k.. so I can build, install and run a compiler for a different CPU  on my intel machine. Only catch is, the output can only be run and tested on the target CPU, which is pretty much logical.. thanks for your time and patience..